# Android Radial menu does not show the menu text

Tags: android, menu, android-widget, radial

I am trying to use Android Radial menu v2, like here:

https://github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Widget-Android/blob/master/src/com/touchmenotapps/radialdemo/RadialMenuActivity.java

This demo works fine as a separate app, but if I include it to my app (or paste the code there), the radial menu does not show the menu texts, the menu has all items that I add there, but no menu captions. Can anybody suggest what could be wrong ? 
I try to change the menutext color, like this

```
mRenderer.setMenuTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

but it does not help.
This library has also radial menu v1, but on landscape mode, the menu is always in the center of the screen, with right part clipped off. How can I avoid this clipping and place the menu where the use touches the screen ?